# Use gpg2 without GUI asking for passphrase

Tags: 13.10, gnupg

How to use gpg2 from command line (i mean... X terminal) without the GUI asking for passphrase?

Answer (score 2):

Change the option `pinentry-program` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` to whatever (console) pinentry client you prefer, eg. `pinentry-curses` (install it if necessary).

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```